# Haskell - Decode message with pattern

Tags: string, haskell, pattern-matching, decode, reverse

I am new to Haskell and I am currently learning it in school. I got a school task where I have to decode a message that contain certain patterns but I have got no idea how to do this.

The pattern looks something like this: If a letter has a consonant followed by the character 'o' and then once again followed by the same consonant as before it should replace that substring ("XoX" where X is a consonant) with only the consonant. For example if I decode the string "hohejoj" it should return "hej". Sorry if I am explaining this poorly but I think you understand.

This is the code I have so far (but it doesn't work):¨

```
karpsravor :: String->String
karpsravor s = karpsravor_help s ""
    where karpsravor_help s res
           |s == "" && (last res) == 'o' = (init res)
           |s==""=res
           |otherwise = karpsravor_help (drop 3 s) (res ++ (consDecode (take 3 s)))

consDecode :: String->String
consDecode a
    |(length a) < 3 = ""
    |a == [(head a)]++"o"++[(head a)] = [(head a)]
    |otherwise = a
```

The code is completely broken and poorly written (dumb method) but I have no other idea for how to solve this. Please help!

Comment: Functions like `head, tail` are partial, and can crash your program if you forget to check for emptiness. They should be avoided, if possible. They are not idiomatic Haskell, which favors pattern matching instead, since it is safe. `length a < 3` is also inefficient compared to pattern matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pattern match](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions) to find occurrences of 'o'. I.e., use

`karpsravorhelp (a:'o':b:rest) res = ...`

You can't have `a:'o':a:rest` in the above, you can't pattern match for equality; you'll need to use a guard to make sure that `a == b`:

`karpsravorhelp (a:'o':b:rest) res 
  | a == b = ...
  | otherwise = ...`

You'll also have to make sure `a` and `b` are consonants, which will just be an 'and' condition for the first guard. For the `otherwise` condition, make sure that the recursive call calls `(b:rest)` since you could have something like `a:'o':b:'o':b:...`.

Also make sure to match for two other patterns:

1. Empty List, `[]`
2. `x:rest`, which must go after the above pattern; this way, it will first attempt to match on the `a:'o':b:rest` pattern, and if that's not there, just take the next letter.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be with [`unfoldr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:unfoldr) from `Data.List`. You can use a `case` expression to pattern match on `a : 'o' : b : rest`, and then check that `a` and `b` are equal and not vowels using a guard `|`. Then just include the base cases for when the pattern doesn't match.

```
notVowel :: Char -> Bool
notVowel = (`notElem` "aeiouAEIOU")

karpsravor :: String -> String
karpsravor = unfoldr $ \str -> case str of
    a : 'o' : b : rest
        | a == b && notVowel a -> Just (a, rest)
    a : rest                   -> Just (a, rest)
    ""                         -> Nothing
```